# API time zone representation

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset

Through an API I would like to expose the timezone of a server. What's the best way of exposing this information? UTC offset only (e.g. +02:00) or shall I use any abbreviation? I'm following the ISO 8601 standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither are the correct choice.  Abbreviations can be ambiguous, and a time zone and a time zone offset are two different things.  A time zone in an API should generally be represented by its IANA [TZ Database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) [identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), such as `America/Los_Angeles`, `Europe/London`, or `Asia/Tokyo`.

You'll find more information about time zones, abbreviations, and  "time zone != offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Do consider also that it's a general [best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532962/634824) to always set a server's time zone to UTC, and to never expect a server to be on any time zone in particular.  Your desire to expose an API for the server's time zone would seem to go against both.  Make sure you have a very good reason before you lock yourself into this design.